# 19.10: Unmet dependencies block install SQL Server Command Line Tools

Tags: command-line, 19.10, sql

I ma trying to install SQL Server Developer Edition in Ubuntu 19.10.

I have followed the article (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15) for installation steps. Every command works in the terminal except for the unixodbc-dev.

The issue that I got in the terminal is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libodbc1 unixodbc msodbcsql mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mssql-tools is already the newest version (17.5.1.1-1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libodbc1 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable
 msodbcsql : Depends: libcurl3 but it is not installable
 unixodbc : Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (>= 2.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried putting the fixes as mentioned in the StackOverflow post [Unable to connect Microsoft SQL-Server and Visual Studio code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123273/unable-to-connect-microsoft-sql-server-and-visual-studio-code/1207821?noredirect=1#comment2027379_1207821)

But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it! You only need to install multi-arch support for 32 bits applications. Apparently it's not already included in the default installation of ubuntu 19.

https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/disco/main/base/multiarch-support

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.29-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./multiarch-support_2.29-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev -f
```